# Natural deduction $\{A \vee L, A \leftrightarrow N, L \rightarrow N\} \vdash N$

Tags: logic

Natural deduction $\{A \vee L, A \leftrightarrow N, L \rightarrow N\} \vdash N$

my work

1- $A \vee L$

2- $A \vee$ Elim FROM 1

3- $A \leftrightarrow N$

4- $A \leftrightarrow$ Elim FROM 3

5- $L \rightarrow N$

6- $L \rightarrow$ Elim FROM 5

is that correct or wrong, need guide please

Comment: $A\vee L\not\vdash A$ That is not how $\vee$ elimination works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [disjunction elimination rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination) allows to eliminate a disjunctive statement by reasoning that if $A$ implies $C$ and $B$ implies $C$, then if $A$ or $B$ is asserted, we can conclude $C$ directly. Symbolically:

$$\frac{\begin{align}
A \rightarrow C, B \rightarrow C, A \lor B
\end{align}}{\begin{align} C \end{align}}$$

That is, whenever both disjunctors, separately, imply a certain sentence, we can just conclude it.

That being said, we can apply it in the following:

> 1. $A ↔ N$, Premise
> 2. $A \rightarrow N$, 1, $↔$E
> 3. $L \rightarrow N$, Premise
> 4. $A \lor L$, Premise
> 5. $N$, 2,3,4, $\lor$E

This shows that $A \lor L, A ↔ N, L → N ⊢ N$ (In fact, note that we don't even need $A ↔ N$, we only need one side of it, $A \rightarrow N$)

Answer (score 2):

That's not how the elimination rules work.

- Conjunction elimination ($\wedge$ elim.) *is* the rule: $$\;P\wedge Q\vdash P$$ However...
- Disjunction elimination ($\vee$ elim.) is the rule: $$P\vee Q, P\to R, Q\to R\vdash R$$
- Biconditional elimination ($\leftrightarrow$ elim.) is the rule: $$P\leftrightarrow Q \vdash P\to Q$$
- Implication elimination ($\to$ elim.) , also known as Modus Ponens (MP), is the rule: $$P, P\to Q \vdash Q$$

  - Contrapositive elimination, also known as Modus Tollens (MT), the rule: $$\neg Q, P\to Q\vdash \neg P$$

---

**tl;dr** Just use Biconditional Elimination and follow with Disjunction Elimination
$$\frac{\begin{align}
A\leftrightarrow N      & \vdash A\to N 
\\
A\vee L, A\to N, L\to N & \vdash N
\end{align}}{\begin{align}A\vee L, A\leftrightarrow N, L\to N & \vdash N\end{align}}$$